# Which IOS build setting would reference to the Derived Data Directory

Tags: ios

I have the following directory:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-fybqdtdocnlinnazwwmhclbrodjm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxx.app

And I need to use something like:

"THIS_DERIVEDDATA_DIR"/xxxxxx.app

Where THIS_DERIVEDDATA_DIR is the build setting I am looking for. Any help is really appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not build setting but Xcode preferences. You can set your own or locate to your derived data fold in Xcode -> Preferences -> locations ..